Как организовать легкое переключение с одного типа базы данных на другой в YII2?
В YII2 есть возможность перенастройки проекта для использования различных баз данных, хотелось бы использовать, но на практике понимаю что не всё так просто....
Например запросы в MongoDB совсем не такие как в Mysql и классы для работы с разными базами имеют разный набор функций.
Прошу поделится опытом.

Совершенна не ясна проблема. причём тут виды запросов и переключение на разные БД? В конфигурации Yii можно поставить много разных БД, потом в коде можно использовать например Yii::$app->dbName->createCommand('QUERY')....... А для mysql можно ещё использовать и ActiveRecord, если хочется

Опишите чётко проблему. Пока что она какая-то размытая и разрозненная. А в случае с заголовком ещё и не совпадает с телом

Нужно сделать, чтобы приложение не напрямую работало с БД, а через репозиторий. Тогда можно сделать лёгкое переключение приложения с одного типа БД на другой. Но переключение внутри репозитория, естественно, придётся делать ручками, переписывая запросы.

Это еще ближе! Можете образно описать как бы вы это сделали?

Стандартный паттерн Репозиторий. Описан повсеместно. Например: https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/11.php

Никак.
Никакой "легкой перенастройки" для использования различных баз данных в природе не существует. Это миф. Сказка.
В теории, если использовать для работы с БД только методы ORM (в Yii2 это Active Record), то перенастройка будет элементарной - достаточно будет поменять тип БД в настройках. А дальше ORM будет сам строить запросы в зависимости от типа СУБД.
Но в реальности одними только методами ORM обойтись невозможно, и в приложении всегда будет SQL (в чистом виде или через QueryBuilder) - и все такие запросы придётся переписывать под новый движок.
А если говорить конкретно про MongoDB, то с ней и того проще - в качестве СУБД для проекта она попросту не подходит, и, соответственно, вопрос  становится неактуальным (если вам всё ещё кажется что подходит, надо прочитать вот эту статью).

спасибо, мысли именно в этом направлении меня и тревожили.... решение должно быть, его не может не быть! :-)

прочитал статью, мой вывод: люди не до конца проработали структуру своих данных и поимели с этого проблемы

Статью вы не поняли, разумеется. В монге в принципе нет никакой структуры, это её главная особенность, в этом её смысл. И поэтому она не подходит ни для чего.
